# Use JSON and JSONP format together in Yii2 REST API

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new in yiiframework.

I want use JSONP and JSON format together in Yii2 REST api, it's means if a api call normal, response get json and if a api call with jsonp ajax, get JSONP result, I can't find anything in forums or stackoverflow to config that. How to i do it? I use `Response::FORMAT_JSON` in behaviors into a controller, but i want use `Response::FORMAT_JSON` and `Response::FORMAT_JSONP` together in behaviors a controller. How to config together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`format`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#$format-detail) property of [`yii\web\Response`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html) class:

```
public class YourController extends Controller {
    /**
     * json/jsonp witching example
     */
    function actionJson(
        $callback = null
    ) {
        // retrieve data to be returned
        $data = array(
            // your data here
        );
        // set "fomat" property
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->format =
            (is_null($callback)) ?
                self::FORMAT_JSON : 
                self::FORMAT_JSONP;
        // return data
        return (is_null($callback)) ?
            $data :
            array(
                'data'     => $data,
                'callback' => $callback
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, But i don't want put code in action, I want config in behaviors section.